# Easiest secure way to exchange data from Perl scripts to Java Android App

Tags: java, android, perl, encryption, encode

I've recently started to learn Java for Android development.

I have a web site that is powered by Perl scripts. What would be the easiest way to exchange data between my Android app and my Perl scripts. (For example: the Android app would get a feed from the Perl scripts where the Perl scripts reads data out of a MySQL database. This data would be passed from the Perl scripts to Android requesting it via http)

So, is there something I could use that would make it easy to encode or encrypt data to be sent when requested by the android app and decode it once it reaches the Android app.

Comment: https is fairly secure, if you check the certs. As for exchange, json or xml.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to build a restfull webservice and use https/tls to make it secure. You could use OAuth for authtentication if you need it.

OAuth: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/385431/Android-RESTful-OAuth-upload-file-to-Dropbox

RESTful client in android: http://ihofmann.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/restful-web-services-with-json-in-android/

RESTfull server in Perl:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/questions/(:question_id)' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    #echo back the question id to the client
    my $result = {question_id => $self->stash('question_id')};
    return $self->render(json => $result)
}
app->start;
```

Comment: I think this has to be `return $self->render(json => $result)`